# = Try Except Pattern?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I find this design pattern comes up a lot:

```
try: year = int(request.GET['year'])
except: year = 0
```

The `try` block can either fail because the key doesn't exist, or because it's not an `int`, but I don't really care. I just need a sane value in the end.

Shouldn't there be a nicer way to do this? Or at least a way to do it on one line? Something like:

```
year = int(request.GET['year']) except 0
```

Or do you guys use this pattern too?

---

Before you answer, I already know about `request.GET.get('year',0)` but you can still get a value error. Wrapping *this* in a try/catch block to catch the value error just means the default value appears twice in my code. Even worse IMO.

Comment: You shouldn't use hard coded literal values anyway, but constants. Like `request.GET.get(REQ_YEAR, DFLT_YEAR)`. That way you have a meaningful constant instead of a meaningless `0` appearing in your code and you don't have to worry about how often it appears.

Comment: @Marjan: I disagree. Why define a constant that will only ever be used in one place, immediately below it? Where it is immediately obvious that it serves as a default value for that particular variable. In general, I agree with you, but not in this case.

Comment: If it is only in one place, maybe, but even then it is easier to find the DFLT_YEAR you might be after than the right occurence of '0' (when searching for that one unit in which it is used once); because it should be a habit that you can rely on without exceptions; because you can put all these constants in one or more separate units, where you can easily view all your default values and other types of constants in relation to each other instead of having to dig for them; because ... Oh loads more. Even back in 1985 I was in a shop were hard coded literals were forbidden (in Cobol :-)

Comment: @Marjan: I do have a file with all my application constants... I just think this particular one is very particular to this function. If you want to find it, find the function. Are you opposed to things like like `amount = CurrencyField(default_value=0)`? Or functions that are declared with default arguments? Sometimes it just makes more sense to put the default value where the variable is declared.

Comment: I guess I've just been bitten once too often by someone not using constants. The point of having these kinds of standards is that they are something you can rely on. Imagine coming back to your code a year from now needing to change the default for a or b and having forgotten the names of the functions... Then suddenly having everything in one place, instead of most in one place and the rest spread out over the whole code base, is invaluable. And yes, I usually also specify default arguments using constants, apart perhaps from nil and true or false.

Comment: @Marjan: Fair enough. I guess I haven't been in the industry long enough for it to bite me yet. One day... I have to learn everything the hard way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a helper function:

```
def get_int(request, name, default=0):
    try:
        val = int(request.GET[name])
    except (ValueError, KeyError):
        val = default
    return val
```

then:

```
year = get_int(request, 'year')
```

It keeps the complexity of the try/catch in one place, and makes for tidy functions, where you have one line per parameter in your view functions.

Comment: I guess this is the obvious sol'n eh? You wrapped it up nicely though. +1 :)

Comment: A lot of people had this answer... please don't kill me for choosing this one (\*coualexgh\*). You other guys have more votes anyway ;)

Answer (score 10):

You're probably better off to use `get()`

```
year = int(request.GET.get("year", 0))
```

This will set year to what ever request.GET['year'] is, or if the key doesn't exist, it will return 0. This gets rid of your KeyError, but you could still have a ValueError from request.GET['year'], if it is not convert'able to an int.

Regarding your question (the try/except), a common idiom in Python is [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp).

**EDIT:**

If you're really concerned, why not write your own method to do this:

```
def myGet(obj, key, type, defaultval):
    try:
        return type(obj.get(key, defaultval))
    except ValueError:
        return defaultval



# In your code
year = myGet(request.GET, 'year', int, 0)
```

Comment: Yeah...that's exactly the problem. It might not be convertible.

Comment: That's true, but that's the nature of Python. I don't agree with catching all possible exceptions (even when you know there are only 2 realistically possible exceptions) and explicitly catching both exceptions is pretty standard, as far as I'm concerned. 

What's wrong with the try/except block? It is very Pythonic.

Comment: I just don't like having a big long list of try/catch blocks at the top of every function to account for every possible error, when all I want is a int! `year` appears in there twice, with what you're suggesting, the default value appears in there twice too. Makes refactoring even more difficult. If you use `year` in once place, but `yaer` in another place, you might not even notice because one of those branches could be pretty rare... and then all of a sudden your app explodes because `year` is actually undefined (or `None`...whatever python does)

Comment: That is true of almost all languages. The scenario you describe is not solved by using if/else blocks instead of try catch.

If you're really concerned, why not write your own method that takes a value, and returns some default you specify?

Comment: Create a wrapper function then that has the try-except in it, and call the wrapper to grab the value?

Answer (score 6):

> Shouldn't there be a nicer way to do
>   this?

There **is** -- it's known as "a function"...:

```
def safeget(adict, key, type, default):
    try: return type(adict.get(key, default))
    except (ValueError, TypeError): return default

year = safeget(request.GET, 'year', int, 0)
```

FWIW, I don't think I've ever used this "pattern" -- the various error cases you're ignoring seem like they should be handled separately for UI reasons (a missing optional field defaulting is fine, but if somebody's mistakenly typed, say, `201o` (the `0` and `o` keys being closed and, in some fonts, their results appearing similar), it generally doesn't seem nice to silently turn their input into `0`.  So, I don't think it's so frequent, nor highly advisable, to warrant anything like a special syntax form in the language, or even a built-in function.

But the nice thing about helper functions like `safeget` is that you and I can peacefully agree to disagree on the design issues involved (maybe we're just used to doing different kinds of software, for example!-) while letting each of us easily have exactly the helper functions each desires in their personal "utilities" modules!-)

Comment: In this particular case, it'll be used in an ajax call. It should never receive the wrong value type unless someone's been tampering with it. Which I guess is all the more reason to let it raise an error, so that *I* know when *I* screwed up... but oh well.

Comment: @Mark Or more seriously, if you detect someone tampering with your website you may wish to log it and do something about it.

Comment: @fmark: They're not going to get any useful information out of tampering with it... but, they might try some more serious attacks after that, so who knows. Maybe I should block them early before they do some serious damage.

Answer (score 2):

No way to do it in one line (that I can think of), but I'd do it like this, using `get()`:

```
try:
    year = int(request.GET.get("year", 0))
except ValueError:
    year = 0
```

Also, it's generally better to catch a specific exception, not *all* exceptions.

Comment: Works, but now you have `0` in there twice, and it's even more verbose. I know you're supposed to catch specific exceptions... but for something simple like this?

Comment: True. In simple cases, a bare `except` isn't bad, but in complicated cases (and who knows when you'll add more lines of code) it can end up masking unanticipated problems.